# can someone help me with phpmyadmin I have already installed apache2, php5, mysql and phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, redhat

When I try start phpmyadmin this error appear:

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>
> The mysql extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

In the php.ini file, I uncommented `extension=mysql.so` line, but doesn't work.

Anyone have another possible solution?

Comment: http://pokit.org/get/img/71f7c183f67647694ac4039b471164e3.jpg

Comment: are you using WAMP / LAMP?

Comment: @user2444244 This is another error than just now

Answer (score 1):

Check your PHP/EXT folder and make sure you have these two files...

```
    php_mysql.dll
    php_mysqli.dll
```

And make sure these two lines are uncommented in php.ini

From...

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll (win)   or  ;extension=php_mysql.so (linux) 
;extension=php_mysqli.dll (win)  or  ;extension=php_mysqli.so (linux)
```

To this...

```
extension=php_mysql.dll  or .so (linux)
extension=php_mysqli.dll or .so (linux)
```

Also....make sure the php.ini file you are editing, is infact the one being used by your system.

I have had issues with WAMP server, where I edit the php.ini file, and nothing changes, but then I searched my hard drive for php.ini, found 3 different ones, and changed them all and then everything worked....and still to this day, I have no idea which one, my WAMP installation is actually 'pointing to'

Comment: "and still to this day, I have no idea which one, my WAMP installation is actually 'pointing to'" `phpinfo()` should tell you just that

Comment: Yeah you would think.... :O

Comment: @PeeHaa my 'loaded file' is C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini

Comment: But when I change anything in this file, nothing changes, but when I change the file in C:\Windows\php.ini, it changes.....is that f***cked up or what

Comment: I think its because Ive had multiple different configurations of WAMP / PHP/ Apache, and I have environment variables all over the place, its just a mess now.....only a complete reinstall/wipe will likely fix